# Custom ErrorStateMatcher does not work when provided on component level

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I want to implement a custom ErrorStateMatcher to show errors even when the formControl is not toched for a matInput from a 3rd party library.

I have implemented an `ErrorStateMatcher` to do this job, but when I provide it on a component level, it does not work.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cax2eb?file=main.ts)

In the example above, it only works when providing it on a module level (one can uncomment the providers in the `app.module.ts`)

**Note**: Manually creating an instance of the `ErrorStateMatcher` and passing it to the `matInput` is not possible to me, since I don't have access to the template where the matInput belongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You import ErrorStateMatcher class from wrong place.
Correct way to import ErrorStateMatcher(like in your module):

> import { ErrorStateMatcher } from '@angular/material';